# SlickGrid doesn't show any data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, slickgrid

My SlickGrid doesn't show any data on my page. If I check the console the result is filled in. The grid shows the headers of the columns. Anyone has any idea why there is no data?
It looks like I do the same as in the [example](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/gh-pages/examples/example1-simple.html).

```
var grid;
var columns = [
            { id: "BO", name: "BO", field: "BO" }, ....
];

var options = {
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    enableColumnReorder: false
};

$(function () 
    $.ajax({
        url: "DataService.svc/DoWork",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: loadData,
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });

});

function loadData(result) {

    console.log(result);
    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", result, columns, options); 
}
```

HTML:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Title" runat="server">
    <link href="Content/slick.grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.event.drag.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/SlickGrid/slick.core.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/SlickGrid/slick.grid.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/EditFeed.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentHolder" runat="server">
    <div id="myGrid" style="width:1200px;height:500px;"></div>  
</asp:Content>
```

{[image]

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: what is that uncaught syntax error you got in the console?

Comment: No idea even if I search in the entire solution I don't seem to find this website. I'm sure this error comes from the Slickgrid files. Didn't have this error until I added the Slickgrid with Nuget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function loadData(result) {

    console.log(result);
    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", result.d, columns, options); 
}
```

If you select result.d you will get the object slick grid accepts.